# Assign Turtles to Random Empty Patch

Tags: random, netlogo, patch

In my setup, I am using the following code to create agents called "darks", and these agents are assigned to a designated set of patches (free-patches).

I am trying to have each turtle assigned to a random patch within the designated area without any of the turtles sharing a patch.

I have stumbled across code that tells a patch to sprout a specific turtle, but can I accomplish my goal without resorting to the patch sprout?

```
  create-darks #-of-darks [
    set shape "person"
    set size 1
    set color black
    move-to one-of free-patches
    ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just get a patch with no darks there.I would also only create a dark if there's enough space.

```
let n-or-remaining-spaces min (list n (count patches with [not any? darks-here]))
create-darks n-or-remaining-spaces
[
;;Your other setup code
move-to one-of patches with [not any? darks-here] 
]
```

Comment: Mattsap, I decided to go with the second option you listed, and that seems to do the trick. It's a much clear start screen. Thank you!